# Dynamically instantiating an inner class nested inside an abstract class

Tags: java, reflection, abstract-class, instantiation, inner-classes

I understand that to instantiate an inner class (i.e. non-static), you need an instance of the enclosing class. This makes things a little more complicated if the enclosing class is abstract (don't ask). Consider the following.

```
abstract class Outer {
   class Inner {}
}
```

Instantiating `Inner` is still plenty doable statically with, for example, an anonymous class, like this.

```
Inner instance = new Outer() {}.new Inner();
```

But then how to accomplish the same thing dynamically with `Constructor.newInstance`? (Notice that I said dynamically; assume you don't know the name of the outer class.) You'd need to pass an instance of the enclosing class for the first argument, as per [JLS 15.9.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.9.3), and if there's a way to create something on the fly to satisfy an abstract parameter, I'm not aware of it (bonus points for any ideas there).

Long story short, I ended up accidentally passing in `null`, like this.

```
Constructor<Inner> constructor = Inner.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Outer.class);
Object argument = null;
Inner instance = constructor.newInstance(argument);
```

Imagine my surprise when that worked. My question is, why did that work? And will that always work?

Comment: "Don't ask" - Trying hard not to ask ...

Comment: @BertF Ha. If you must know, I'm writing a method that tries to instantiate a given class on a best-effort basis, and I want to handle all possible cases. An inner class nested inside an abstract class is one such possible case.

Comment: Makes perfect sense - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It worked because the constructor just sets the Outer.this field. It probably should check that its not null, (so it fails fast) but its faster if it doesn't.

I wouldn't rely on it always working, there is every possibility that different JVMs, even different updates will work differently.

based on your previous example, this should work.

```
Inner instance = constructor.newInstance(new Outer(){});
```

Comment: So, if a method in `Inner` was called that tried to dereference `Outer.this`, would that result in a `NullPointerException`, or what?

Comment: If it tried to use it, it would fail.  You could still test it and use in the same manner as any field which is null. Its just you might not expect it to be.

Comment: Alright. I'm gonna test this out after I get some sleep. I'll probably accept your answer tomorrow after I've taken a look at it. Thanks. As for passing in `new Outer( ) { }`, that only works if you know about `Outer`. I want to be able to do this given an arbitrary `Class` object from the outside world.

Comment: So, I took a look and gleaned some useful tidbits. I didn't understand before that inner classes end up totally separate from their enclosing classes after compilation, with the only link being an instance field referring to the enclosing instance that must be passed to the inner class constructors. Now that I understand that, this makes a lot more sense. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: BTW: If possible, it is better to make inner classes, a nested class by making them "static" this improve performance and reduces needless dependencies between the outer class, and classes inside them.

Comment: I actually can't imagine myself ever wanting to nest a non-static inner class inside an abstract class. This is just one possible case I want to handle for a method I'm writing that takes a given `Class` object (e.g. `Outer.Inner.class`) and tries to instantiate the class it represents. And for the record, since I commented on your answer, you can @tag me to make sure I'm notified of your responses, but if you don't, I have no idea that you commented.

Comment: @Charlatan, I didn't know it did that. I just use the mail box symbol next to my name at the top. It shows all comments etc relating to things I have posted.

Comment: Yeah, I usually just look top right to see if I have any new notifications.

Comment: @Charlatan, That stopped working for me about a month ago, only the email icon works...